# After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing Android Test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to test the room database using junit4, I'm using flows and coroutines when I get to run the test I get `kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [DispatchedCoroutine{Active}@773f274]` 
I have tried before to use runBlocking and runBlockingTest and runTest
the test class ->

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) // Annotate with @RunWith
class TaskDatabaseTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instatExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    private lateinit var database: TaskDatabase
    private lateinit var dao: TaskDao

    private val testCoroutineDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
    private val testCoroutineScope = TestScope(testCoroutineDispatcher)

 
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testCoroutineDispatcher)

        database = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            TaskDatabase::class.java
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
        dao = database.taskDao()
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        database.close()
    }

    @Test
    fun insert() = testCoroutineScope.runTest {
        // Arrange
        val task = Task("do exercise", id = 1)
        dao.insert(task)

        val tasks = dao.getTasksSortedByName("", false).toList()
        assertThat(tasks).contains(task)

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you code is that flow is continuously emitting data and `runTest` is waiting for it to finish. But this is never gonna happen. So after 60000 ms the runTest will throw an error. You can use `turbine` library to test flows. You can do it like: -
1). Add following dependency in your module level `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation 'app.cash.turbine:turbine:0.12.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'app.cash.turbine:turbine:0.12.1'
}
```

2). And then,

```
@Test
fun insert() = runTest {
    val task = Task("do exercise", id = 1)
    dao.insert(task)

    val task2 = Task("do homework", id = 2)
    launch {
        delay(1000)
        dao.insert(task2)
    }

    dao.getTasksSortedByName().test {
        val tasksList = awaitItem()
        assertThat(tasksList).contains(task)

        val tasksList2 = awaitItem()
        assertThat (tasksList2).contains(task2)

        cancel()
    }
    

}
```